# We should [edit] this tag out of all questions

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edit) tag has the following rather vague description:

> to modify (a computer file) by, for example, deleting, inserting, moving, or copying text.

Predictably, it's used for editing just about anything - files, databases, HTML pages, purchase orders, PDF documents...

This is a very ambiguous Meta tag that adds little to no valuable information. It does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts, and many of the topics it does identify aren't even on topic.

Can we edit this tag out of everything?

Comment: I wonder how many people are using it just to indicate the question itself has been edited. (Hopefully not many but probably more than zero.)

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, the tag itself is largely meaningless, so that wouldn't surprise me too much.

Comment: the question is is there a silver or gold member for this tag

Comment: @nbk the only user with the most answers on this tag has 43. So no. Also, the user seems to be adding to many questions it answered both edit and key tag.

Comment: Other than small scale tags that can be done by 1 person on meta, is the burnination process still at a standstill?